# Facebook share image is not displaying

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have two issues

1. I want to share my application on facebook. I provided a logo of proper size 1024*1024.
   But while i click on the share button logo is not getting display.

   Code:

   ```
   <div id="share" class="fb-share-button btn btn-primary" data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/bjpsupporter/" data-type="button_count"></div>

   <script>
   FB.init({
      appId: '518889444896033', 
      cookie: true,
      status: true, xfbml: true
   });
   function shareWithFacebook() {
      FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'
      });
   }
   ```

   I dont know whats wrong in it.
2. Facebook URLs cannot be crawled. Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed

   I am getting this error.

   for "http://apps.everycrave.me/facebook/" canvas url I am getting error

   > "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."
   >   these are my settings details.

   Domain:- www.apps.everycrave.me
   Canvas Page:- https://apps.facebook.com/bjpsupporter
   Canvas URL:- http://apps.everycrave.me/facebook/

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> I provided a logo of proper size 1024*1024. But while i click on the share button logo is not getting display.

Its by default. The proper size logo that you are mentioning is for the app center. In the dialog, it will show the default size only, you cant do anything regarding this.

> "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must m

You have not properly setup the settings of your application. Pl check whether the following settings are setup properly:

- domain
- canvas url
- secure canvas ur;

Comment: yah its properly done,,,,, Still getting the error.
And how to resolve the first problem.?

Comment: What problem? I've already said that you cant do anything about that, share dialog structure is default.

Comment: That I've explained you. Unless you show me what have you added to these settings I can't help you. Pls edit your ques and add these settings

Comment: Also make sure you have written correct `App id` and `app secret` in your code.

Comment: PS dont forget to click on the right tick if helped. Good luck :)

Comment: Still its not working,,,,,,,,, Everything is correct.